# Data-Bind e OnClick no mesmo botão

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Eu tenho um botão que possui um `data-bind`, chamando uma função *JS* que está funcionando perfeitamente.

Porém, preciso chamar outra função no mesmo botão, só que em *C#*, na classe *CSS* da minha pagina, se eu deixo o `data-bind` e o `onclick`, apenas o `data-bind` funciona, mas se eu tiro o `data-bind`, o `onclick` funciona normalmente. Segue código:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnBuscar" runat="server" onclick="btnVisualizar_Click" 
    Text="Buscar" class="btn btn-info" data-bind="click: buscar"/>
```

Nesse caso, apenas o `data-bind` está sendo chamado, o `onclick` não funciona. 
Vale ressaltar que se eu tirar o `data-bind`, a outra função funciona normalmente.

Comment: Se tu precisa chamar as duas funções, acho que tu pode chamar a segunda função dentro a primeira função a ser chamada no JS.

Comment: Entendi @EdwardRamos, mas como eu poderia chamar a outra função? Posso mandar a função que eu utilizo no js adiantando que é uma função que chama o mapa do google.

Comment: Aparentemente sim...

Answer (score 1):

Tu pode chamar a segunda função dentro da primeira função (acho que isso vai resolver o teu problema), se for apenas isso, tenta fazer assim:

```cs
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnBuscar" runat="server" onclick="btnVisualizar_Click" 
    Text="Buscar" class="btn btn-info"/>
```

JS:

```js
function btnVisualizar_Click() {
    buscar(); // chama a segunda função
    alert("A função chamada foi 'btnVisualizar_Click'");
}

function buscar() {
    alert("A função chamada foi 'buscar'");
}
```

Qualquer coisa, comenta ai que a gente ajuda.